# Dynamically Route React just Once

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I am using React Router. As you can see below I am dynamically creating routes. Routes' path data is coming from the api. If I go to the page I am creating or refresh the page I can see 404 page for a millisecond. How can I create routes for once?

Navigation bar is rendering itself everytime when I refresh the page. Should I change where I am routing?
If so where should I place it?

```
class NavigationBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          JSON: []
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        callApi('news')
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ JSON: data})
        })
    }

 render() {
   return(

       ...(unnecessary code)

       <Router>
         <Switch>

          ...

          {this.state.JSON.map((value) => {
                    return <Route exact path={value.Link} render={(props) => <News header={value.Header} 
                content={value.Content} image={value.Image} />}/>
           })}
         </Switch>
       </Router>
   )
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the best solution I've found is  calling  api at top of the project in **App.js** and passing the route info as props to components.

Also I used `<Link to="">` instead of `<a href="">` so page won't be refreshed when links are clicked.